# Re-run external JavaScript with NuxtLink

Tags: javascript, dom, nuxt.js, single-page-application, pageload

I´m using multiple external JavaScript-Files for the client- /frontend-Design of my Nuxt Application ( Nuxt Universal Mode, server-side rendering + client-side navigation ), putting them in the nuxt.config.js-file.

```
nuxt.config.js

<script>
export default {
  head () {
    return {
      script: [
        { src: '/scripts/jquery.min.js', body: true },
        { src: '/scripts/jquery.dropotron.min.js', body: true },
        { src: '/scripts/browser.min.js', body: true },
        { src: '/scripts/breakpoints.min.js', body: true },
        { src: '/scripts/util.js', body: true },
        { src: '/scripts/main.js', body: true },
        { src: '/scripts/owa.js', body: true }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Everything´s working well on initial pageview, but unfortunately when using **NuxtLink**, to navigate to another page, the EventListeners vanish. I conclude from this, that the Virtual DOM is re-rerendered but once it´s finished, the JavaScript functions doesn´t run again.

Of course I could use a-Tags instead of NuxtLink, so the whole site will load again, so will do the scripts, but that´s bad practice and has nothing to do with SPA.

I´ve already tried Nuxt Middleware, but removing the Scripts ( seen in the example code ) in the Head doesn´t work.

```
middleware/rerunJs.js

  const scripts = context.app.head.script
  context.app.head.script = undefined
  context.app.head.script = scripts
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

### Update

> ### Client Console Output - Initial page load

```
Logging: rerunJs.js in middleware directory
Server based middleware
Print context.app.head.script:
[
  { src: '/scripts/jquery.min.js', body: true, defer: true },
  { src: '/scripts/jquery.dropotron.min.js', body: true, defer: true },
  { src: '/scripts/browser.min.js', body: true, defer: true },
  { src: '/scripts/breakpoints.min.js', body: true, defer: true },
  { src: '/scripts/util.js', body: true, defer: true },
  { src: '/scripts/main.js', body: true, defer: true },
  { src: '/scripts/owa.js', body: true }
]
Logging: index.vue in Nuxt pages directory
Logging: jquery.dropotron.min.js in static/scripts directory
Logging: main.js in static/scripts directory
```

> ### Client Console Output - Navigating to Route '/' with NuxtLink

```
Logging: rerunJs.js in middleware directory
Client based middleware
Print context.app.head.script:
Array(7) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
```

Comment: Are your running checks to see if the elements are grabbable upon load? Any errors showing, if scripts are loading up and you can determine by adding a simple console.log("loaded file 12345"), I'd think it's because you're not running the scripts when the entire page is loaded and things aren't there in time. Templates can stir this issue/etc.

Comment: window.onload = () => {}; Maybe give this one a go, anything nested in this function should load when full load has occurred.

Comment: This is a super broad question. It depends a lot on what is actually in the code you're trying to run. Also depends of the way you do load those. You could essentially load of this into a Nuxt plug-in. But I'm not sure that using jQuery into something modern like Nuxt is a good idea since jQuery is imperative. Prefer using VueJS and it's declarative style of coding. Hence, using "state" rather than DOM events is the prefered way nowadays. You will have far more control over the things and a lot of tooling to help you.

Comment: @blanknamefornow I did wrote checks. As you can see in the update, Nuxt lifecycle starts with middleware ( if-statement: process.server or process.client ). It is followed by the JS from the index.vue page. Then the head with the scripts starts running them. These external scripts consist of IIFE´s. For example dropotron-Script: `(function(e){ jquery.dropotron.min.js code ... })(jQuery);`

Of course, there´s no Logging from inside the IIFE´s when using 'NuxtLink'. Besides the array is being printed differently.

Comment: @blanknamefornow there must be a Nuxt-way to do things like 'window.onload = () => {};'. When I put it in the script section on pages/index.vue it throws error window is not defined. I searched the docs for a place to run some JS when the page is loaded after using NuxtLink, but didn´t find anything.

Comment: @kissu That totally makes sense. I was hoping, to solve this one without going so far, but it seems like I have to take some time to transfer the project to being declarative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

To re-run external JavaScript (i.e. jQuery) when navigating to another page using NuxtLink with Nuxt setted up to Universal Mode, two lifecycle hooks are to be used.

First, middleware should remove the scripts from head. Be sure, that only client will remove the scripts. On initial pageload, middleware is server based and scripts run, even without triggering them.

```
middleware/rerunJs.js

...
  if (process.client) {
    context.app.head.script = undefined
  }
...
```

Afterwards the mounted-Hook of the desired page should append the scripts to head and end of body.

```
pages/index.vue

...
  mounted () {
    (function LoadMyJs () {
      const docHeadObj = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
      const jqueryScript = document.createElement('script')
      jqueryScript.outerHTML = '<scr' + 'ipt data-n-head="ssr" src="/scripts/jquery.min.js" data-body="true">' + ' </scr' + 'ipt>'
      jqueryScript.src = '/scripts/jquery.min.js'
      jqueryScript.defer = true

      docHeadObj.appendChild(jqueryScript)

      document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + queryScript.outerHTML 
    }())
  }
...
```